# Docker. Access to php image from Ubuntu image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create my first dev environment based on docker.

My host is Windows 10
I need to create stack Ubuntu:14.04 + php in separate images.

**Dockerfile for ubuntu:**
FROM ubuntu:14.04

**Dockerfile for php:**
FROM php:5.6-fpm

Just that simple. W\o any additional parameters at that point.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  os:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/ubuntu/Dockerfile
    container_name: ubuntu
    tty: true
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: ./.docker/php
    container_name: php
```

Then `docker-compose up --build`

**result is:**

```
Building os
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 971bb384a50a
Step 2/2 : LABEL maintainer="Andrey Kryukov"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d71726444ee

Successfully built 3d71726444ee
Successfully tagged nnrservice_os:latest
Building php
Step 1/2 : FROM php:5.6-fpm
 ---> 8d3dc6499e61
Step 2/2 : LABEL maintainer="Andrey Kryukov"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b6fc0c83131b

Successfully built b6fc0c83131b
Successfully tagged nnrservice_php:latest
Starting ubuntu ... done
Starting php    ... done
Attaching to ubuntu, php
php    | [24-Aug-2018 05:14:01] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php    | [24-Aug-2018 05:14:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

And then `docker-compose exec os /bin/sh`
**result is:**

```
#
```

W\o any errors. So I expected that php will be available inside my console. But no!

```
# php -v
/bin/sh: 1: php: not found
#
```

What I am doing wrong? Or maybe I losing some important concept?

Comment: I suggest you can try `docker exec -it your_docker_name bash` after you **run up** your service 
 (maybe docker-compose up -d) and try it again.  **your_docker_name** is the name which shows in `docker ps`

Comment: nope. Similar result (

PS C:\github\NNRService> docker exec -it ubuntu bash

root@4f244e85fe73:/# php -v

bash: php: command not found

root@4f244e85fe73:/#

Comment: That's a right result because you didn't install php in your Ubuntu mirror. Actually, **os** is useless. Each docker mirror are different services, there are **coupled**. you should run this command to **php**, it will be nice to change a name of this mirror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker-compose exec os /bin/sh
```

You're connecting to the `os` container and trying to execute `php`, which is in the `PHP` container. Obviously, that will not work because the os container has only the base utils, not the PHP libraries and PHP-FPM application which is in the php container, as evident by

```
php    | [24-Aug-2018 05:14:01] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php    | [24-Aug-2018 05:14:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connection
```

Why do you need an OS container and a PHP container? That defeats the purpose. The php container will have a base OS + required applications/libraries for PHP. You don't need two, if you goal is to just run PHP

Comment: My task is to make the most accurate copy of my production environment. With OS version and php version. And many othet things, but later. I'm at the very starting point of docker learning )

Comment: to reiterate, you don't need an OS container. You target the docker engine, not the OS. Compose and multi-containers makes sense when you want to have an application server,  webserver, database server containers. If you haven't yet, please read an overview of Docker on their docs page. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to build webserver with specified versions of all its components. Spec version of Ubuntu, spec ver of php, mysql and so on. Thats why I'm trying to use multi-containers

Comment: what I am saying is you _don't_ need Ubuntu because your php, mysql etc containers _will_ have that.